# Read mydocument folder path using registry class in .net

Tags: .net

i want read My Document Folder path using Registry Class in net,kindly help me.i dot not use Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocument.

Comment: Do you want to use the Registry class for sure? There are easier ways to get this path.

Answer (score 3):

As @nitram says do you have to use the registry?

```
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```